# Find the image under $T$ Linear Transformation - Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

We are asked

Consider the linear operator $T:\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ with standard matrix

$$ A = \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
    1 & 1\\
    0 & 1\\
    \end{array}\right]
$$

Find the image under $T$ of the line $x_1 + 2x_2 = 3$

I do not know how to start the problem.

Comment: Parameterize the line $x_1 + 2x_2=3$.

Comment: So $x_1 = t$ and $x_2 = 2t-3$?

Comment: use $x_1 = 3-2x_2$ and find the image of $(3-x_2, x_2)$ and then get rid of $x_2.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's parametrize your line.  There are an infinite numbers of ways to do so, but here's one easy way:
Let $x_2=t$.  Then $x_1 = -2t+3$.  Thus $\mathbf r(t) = (x_1,x_2)=(-2,1)t+(3,0)$.

Now let's see where $A$ maps these vectors $\mathbf r(t)$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} -2t+3 \\ t\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} (-2t+3)+(t) \\ (0) + (t)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -t+3 \\ t\end{bmatrix}$$

Thus $A$ maps $\mathbf r(t)$ to $\mathbf r'(t) = (-t+3,t)$.  Now see if you can write $\mathbf r'(t)$ in the form $ax_1+bx_2=c$.

Comment: OK. I see it now. Thanks a lot, much obliged.